# Listening on the host on a named pipe for a command from a docker container

Tags: bash, docker

I'm trying to be able to restart a docker container from within the container, by sending a command through a named pipe and listening for it on the host machine.

However it appears that the host machine is not listening for it - I call

```
echo "incoming" > host_directory/cdm_container_pipe3
echo "restart" > host_directory/cdm_container_pipe3
```

And the first call just blocks, as if nothing is reading from the pipe.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash -p

#

if [ -z "$container_id" ]; then
    container_id=0
fi

let "container_id=container_id+1"

#

container_name="cdm_container$container_id"

pipe="cdm_container_pipe$container_id"
if [ ! -p $pipe ]; then
  echo 'Creating pipe'
  mkfifo $pipe
fi


#

start_container() {
    docker rm $container_name
    docker run -v ~/dev/obd:/host_directory -it --name $container_name --privileged cdm_image:latest
}

#

start_container

#

while true
do
    if read line <$pipe; then
        COMMAND=$(cat $pipe)
        echo "received from pipe: $COMMAND"

        if [ $COMMAND == "restart" ]; then
            echo " updating repo and restarting container "
            docker stop $container_name
            git pull origin master
            start_container
        fi
    fi
done
```

For reference, I tried a cut down version which does *not* start the docker container:

```
#!/bin/bash -p

pipe="test_pipe"
if [ ! -p $pipe ]; then
  echo 'Creating pipe'
  mkfifo $pipe
fi

#

while true
do
    if read line <$pipe; then
        COMMAND=$(cat $pipe)
        echo "received from pipe: $COMMAND"
    fi
done
```

I was able to get this to work successfully, both piping in from another  terminal and piping in from a running container using host_directory/pipe_name

Is there an issue with the while loop not running after the docker container is started?  Should I try to run the container in a different thread?

Thanks,
Ian

Comment: Don't you just want `COMMAND=$line` (though you don't need `COMMAND`, just use `$line` directly). `read line` has already read the (single) line written to the pipe; `cat $pipe` is blocking waiting for more input that isn't coming.

Comment: While that is an improvement (thank you), it doesn't solve the core issue which is that the first input into the pipe isn't being read at all...

Comment: Oh the issue is that the docker run command is blocking by the looks of it

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to just have your process exit, and set a [restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies---restart) that restarts the container when this happens.  If an operator wants to restart the container from the outside, they can `sudo docker restart` it given its name or container ID.

(If you’re looking at clustered deployment solutions like Kubernetes, relying on the orchestrator is even better.  The usual way to handle problems like “the database isn’t ready yet” is “just crash and let the orchestrator restart you later”, for example, and the universal big-hammer way to fix misbehaving Kubernetes pods is to just delete them let and the orchestrator recreate them.  It’ll also be hard to wire something like a named pipe out from a process running on an arbitrary node.)

Comment: That seems like a good solution, but will it enable me to run git pull on the host before restarting the container?

Answer (score 0):

docker run blocks, so for this to function I need to run it with -d (and an ongoing command)